# Firebase returning null in the data that comes from a firestore document in Google Play Store version

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crashlytics

I have this error that the Firebase Crashlytics has stored. 
The scenario is simple, in a productive environment (by downloading the app from Google play) when I try to obtain a document within a collection in Firestore, the document values ​​are saved in the object, but these are void. This issue does not happens if I compile the app from Android Studio to my Samsung s8, but if I upload de the version to the Google Play Store, I download it, then I'm having this problem.

Here is the stack trace error from crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
   at com.syntepro.appbeneficiosbolivia.SplashActivity.lambda$null$1(SplashActivity.java:25)
   at com.syntepro.appbeneficiosbolivia.-$$Lambda$SplashActivity$yoUq7EYShrgir_wINryItOzyIMs.onSuccess(-.java:4)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(zzn.java:6)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

And this is my code from Java:

```
public void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    int DURACION_SPLASH = 2000;
    if (user != null) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            FirebaseUser user1 = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            DocumentReference ref = db.collection("Usuarios").document(Objects.requireNonNull(user1).getUid());
            ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(documentSnapshot).exists()) {
                        try {
                        Usuario readUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(Usuario.class);
                        if (readUser != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.welcome) + " " + Objects.requireNonNull(readUser).getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String pais = Objects.requireNonNull(readUser).getPais();
                            String cod = readUser.getCodigoArea();
                            String abr = readUser.getAbreviacion();
                            String moneda = readUser.getMoneda();

                            loadData(pais, cod, abr, moneda);

                            if (readUser.getTyc() != null && Objects.requireNonNull(readUser).getTyc().equals("1")) {
                                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                readAccessUser(Objects.requireNonNull(currentUser));
                            } else if (readUser.getTyc() != null && readUser.getTyc().equals("0")) {
                                startActivity(TyCActivity.getIntent(SplashActivity.this, "0"));
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                readAccessUser(Objects.requireNonNull(currentUser));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                } else {
                    Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "Get User -> Error getting data");
                }
            });
        }, DURACION_SPLASH);
    } else {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }, DURACION_SPLASH);
    }
}
```

I don't know what else it could be, I hope you can help me, because I can't replicate this problem in dev environment, UAT environment or compiling the App from Android Studio to my phone with de Firebase JSON of production environment.

Thanks

EDIT: This only happens when I sign the app for make it as apk-release to upload it to the Play Store.

Comment: Until someone gives a solution, make sure you're using the latest version of firebase libraries.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please also respond with @AlexMamo